# RCRD_DSNT_EXIST while creating user event script with aftersubmit function

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to write a user event script which loads the current record and populates a line item value through search after submit record. But, it is giving an error RCRD_DSNT_EXIST, even though the record exists.

````
function afterSubmit_SO(type){
    try
    {        
        //var record_type = nlapiGetRecordType();
        var recordID = nlapiGetRecordId();    
        var context = nlapiGetContext();
        var recordOBJ = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder',recordID);
        var source = context.getExecutionContext();
       if(source == 'userinterface') 
        {
            var line_count = recordOBJ.getLineItemCount('item');
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'line count ', line_count);
            for(var i = 1; i <= line_count; i++)
            {
                var itemID = recordOBJ.getLineItemValue('item','item',i); 
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'item ID', itemID);             
                var filter = new Array();
                filter[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', itemID);                    
                var columns = new Array();
                columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custitem_web_market_availability');               
                var a_search_results = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filter,columns);               
                if(a_search_results)
                {   
                    for(var x = 0; x < a_search_results.length; x++) 
                    {                    
                        var item_web_availability = a_search_results[x].getText('custitem_web_market_availability');                                                                                            
                        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'value', item_web_availability);
                    }
                }       recordOBJ.setLineItemValue('item','custcol_web_item_availability',i,item_web_availability);                
            }    
            var submitID = nlapiSubmitRecord(recordOBJ, true, true);
        } 
    }  
    catch(exception)
    {
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Exception Caught ','' + exception);
    }

    return true;     
}```
````

Comment: Since you have *salesorder* hardcoded in `nlapiLoadRecord`, make sure that your script is deployed only on salesorder or add a return statement before.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your script is executing on the delete operation.  I did not see any checking for this in the code you provided.  If it is a delete operation then the after submit user event script wont be able to load the deleted record, this is why you get the error.

The `type` parameter of your afterSubmit function should contain the operation type.  You can something like `if (type == 'delete') { return true;}` at the top of your script.